# The Configure block for the Job DSL scan by webhook is not working

Tags: jenkins, traits, jenkins-job-dsl

I am using the below Configure block for the **scan by webhook** functionality in Jenkins Job DSL.

Environment: Jenkins and Bitbucket

```
traits << 'com.igalg.jenkins.plugins.mswt.trigger.ComputedFolderWebHookTrigger' {
            token("TEST_HOOK")
        }
```

The above block is not working.

But the below **periodic** trigger syntax is working with out any issues.

```
it / 'triggers' << 'com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.computed.PeriodicFolderTrigger'{
            spec '* * * * *'
            interval "60000"
        }
```

As we want to use the scan by webhook functionality. Kindly correct my **scan by webhook** syntax

Comment: Hi akileshds, could you please elaborate a bit more on _WHAT_ is not working? Do you get an exception message. If so, can you put that snippet in here as well. This will make it easier for others to see if they had a similar problem and how they fixed it. Give the reader a bit more context. That will get your problem fixed sooner, and it will be helpful for future readers as well

Answer (score 1):

The Job DSL Pipeline provides some declarative Parts for triggering a job either on changes or scheduled.
Another case can be the **Multibranch Pipeline**, where any branch is configured by the included Jenkinsfile. In order to create Jobs for a new branch, the Task **"Scan Multibranch Pipeline Now"** has to be executed either manually or scheduled. This can be programmatically(schedule) done via the **configure** block inside the Multibranch Pipeline Job:

```
 multibranchPipelineJob("JobName") {
 ...     
 configure { node ->
            def periodicFolderTrigger = node / triggers / 'com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.computed.PeriodicFolderTrigger' {
                spec('H H * * *')
                //4 hours (60000(Milliseconds)*60(Minutes)*4(hours)
                interval(60000*60*4)
                }
            }
 }
```

The **webhook** Solution, is **more elegant**, but you need the Jenkins plugin https://plugins.jenkins.io/multibranch-scan-webhook-trigger/ to be installed. Programmatically you can activate this via the following way:

```
 multibranchPipelineJob("JobName") {
 ...     
 configure { node ->
     def webhookTrigger = node / triggers / 'com.igalg.jenkins.plugins.mswt.trigger.ComputedFolderWebHookTrigger' {
                spec('')
                token("TESTTOKEN")
            }
      }
 }
```